# Add excel macro from service account

Tags: c#, excel, vba, service, local-system-account

Currently I try to write a service (run by system account) that creates macro in an Excel workbook.  It seems that I can open excel, create a new workbook, add data and markup to it, but when I try to add a macro to the excel, I get a security message:

"Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted"

I do have "Trust access to vba project object medal" turned on.  However, is it possible that this setting is user-dependent instead of machine dependent?  Is there a way to let my C# service have access to the macros of the excel workbooks it creates (at time of creation...)

thanx!!!

Best regards,

Jan

Comment: I can't verify this at the moment, otherwise I would put it into an answer, but I am pretty sure that the security settings for Excel (or Office applications in general) are user specific.  So you would have to change it for all users on a specific machine, and if a new user logs in, you'll need to change it for them.

Answer (score 0):

psubsee2003, thx for the reaction...

In the end I solved the problem like this:

The excel file:

- I created an excel file that has no data in it and one macro
- The macro runs only when there is data in the sheet (if cell x = empty then exit sub)
- The macro sets print ranges correct

The service:

- Service opens the excel file
- Adds the data
- Service saves a copy of the original file (meaning the original file stays untouched)